# Possibility of memory leaks in this code block

Tags: 2013, custom, object-model, memory-leak

I have a tool using a similar code block as follows.

```
private void createDiscussions()
{                        
   SPWeb newCommunitySite = null;

   try
   {    

     using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteURL))
     {
      .
      .
      .
      newCommunitySite = site.OpenWeb();    
      .
      .
      .
     }
      newCommunitySite.Dispose();
   }
   catch()
   {
    .
    .
    .
   }
   finally
   {
    newCommunitySite.Dispose();
   }
}
```

Can this code cause memory leaks ?

Although the code looks nicely wrapped in the `Using` and `try-catch` blocks, I have the doubt because the `SPWeb` object was declared outside of `Using` and `try-catch` blocks. Will that be disposed properly(without causing leaks) in all scenarios ?

Comment: At compile time, your SPSite with the using statement to is rewritten as an try finally. It will also declare the variable outside the try, and it handles the IDisposable in the finally. So nothing wrong with declaring it outside the try.

Comment: Nice to know that Anders...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though `SPWeb` is declared outside of `try catch` block, it is initialized inside `try` block. And it is disposed inside `try` and `finally` blocks. So there won't be any memory leak. Only issue I see in the code is that in the `finally` block, there should be a `null` check before an attempt is made to `Dispose SPWeb` object.

```
   finally
   {
    if (newCommunitySite != null)
    newCommunitySite.Dispose();
   }
```

The reason for this is the below line may throw exception for several reasons:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteURL))
```

Comment: Great explanation. So, do you mean that, if i don't use `if (newCommunitySite != null)` before disposing the SPWeb object, the code may throw an exception again in the finally block ?

Comment: Yes, that is right.